# minecraft: How to make a single Item class to fire multiple entity types

Tags: java, minecraft

I am currently working on creating a mod for Minecraft.  I am trying to create one Item class that I can use to fire projectile entities.  This would just before testing the entities before making an individualized class.  I am trying to use an input in the constructor that takes any child entity of my parent class for projectile entities (`AbstractEntityProjectile`) as the type.

I have tried this with both `?` and `T`:

```
public EntityGun(<? extends AbstractEntityProjectile> entity) {
  /* code */
}
```

Is there a different syntax for doing this?  Or do I need to go about this differently?

Comment: just use public EntityGun(AbstractEntityProjectile entity). This will pass a reference to an object that must have extended the Abstract class. The reference though will be AbstractEntityProjectile, so you will only be able to invoke methods from the class unless you cast to the Class that has implemented the abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, to pass a parameter to the constructor of which the Object class has extended the AbstractEntityProjectile abstract class, simply use:

```
public EntityGun (AbstractEntityProjectile entity) {
    /* code */
}
```

To initialize an EntityGun object, you class of the entity must have extended the AbstractEntityProjectile class. Note that entity will have the type AbstractEntityProjectile, hence you will only be able to invoke methods that explicitly defined in the abstract AbstractEntityProjectile class or those that are inherited by AbstractEntityProjectile. To work with methods introduced in the 'true' class of the parameter, you will need to cast it to the appropriate class.